# Jane is back in May, by____ the new house should be finished

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, exam-questions

> Jane is back in May, by____ the new house should be finished.
>
> A. which B. that C. whom D. when

"when" is the answer, and I know its grammar.

My question is whether or not "which" works and why.

---

relative question: [Stephen Hawking believes that the earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ life has developed gradually](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165175/stephen-hawking-believes-that-the-earth-is-unlikely-to-be-the-only-planet-l)

Comment: **Which** alone does not work, but you could say, "Jane is back in May, by **which time** the new house should be finished."

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use *when* in the given example. Some options:

> Jane is back in May, **<del>by</del> when** the new house should be finished.
>   Jane is back in May, by **then** the new house should be finished.
>   Jane is back in May, **by/at which time** the new house should be finished.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not a native English speaker, but how about "until" instead of by? Here's an example: "I am to report to Govt. on the 17th May, until when I can publish nothing." from "The Beast in the Mosquito: The Correspondence of Ronald Ross and Patrick Manson". Considering it is a published book (which must have been edited and proofread before publishing, I think), it should constiute a valid example. Seeing that crossed out 'by' above, I feel the need to suggest this aternative. However, if "by" is irreplaceable, I'd say "by when".