# Stephen Hawking believes that the earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ life has developed gradually

Tags: relative-clauses, exam-questions

(I'm reading a grammar textbook, which contains the question and clams it was written for China's National College Entrance Examination in 2010. I checked, and it was.)

> Stephen Hawking believes that the earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ life has developed gradually.
>
> A. that
>   B. where
>   C. which
>   D. whose

The answer is "where", and I understand.

My question is whether "that" works and why.

I think we can say "I will never forget the place where/that/∅ we met for the first time."

---

related: [Jane is back in May, by____ the new house should be finished](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165172/jane-is-back-in-may-by-the-new-house-should-be-finished)

Comment: Better than all the above: "on which"

Comment: D would also work though. "Stephen Hawking believes that the earth is unlikely to be the only planet whose life has developed gradually" -- this has a somewhat different meaning (it implies knowledge of other planets with life) but it still parses and makes sense.

Comment: @fluffy nit: "whose" would imply that you're thinking about "the life of Earth", or "Earth's life", which is not _quite_ standard (American) English IMHO. I'd agree more wholeheartedly with "...only planet whose _fauna_ has developed...", or "whose _biosphere_ has"; but "whose _life_ has" feels just a tiny bit off. (Still a tiny enough bit that I wish D hadn't been listed as a wrong answer!)

Comment: Grammatically, all 4 are correct (although they have very different meanings). But only answer B makes sense if you have been given a text and we’re asked to answer these questions based on the text (answers a and c imply that life develops the planet instead of vice verse and d implies that life on other planets is a given and that the speed of development is the issue in question)

Comment: @abligh Why is "on which" better than "where"? I was told 
relative adverbs "when/where/why" = "preposition + which" or "which/that/∅ ... preposition"

Comment: @ZhangJian I'm not entirely sure why, but at least to this native (UK) English speaker (and apparently 21 upvoters) it sounds better. I would guess it has something to do with not thinking of a planet as an obvious indicator of place.

Comment: “On which” means something different than “where”; “on which” in this case implies that it developed *on* the planet only, rather than also in the planet (in its rocks, in the water). I believe that Hawkins said “where” intentionally, rather than “on which”

Comment: A better single word (albeit a somewhat pretentious one) would be [whereupon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whereupon). The reason _on_ or _upon_ are preferred is that _where_ is rather inspecific. It could also just mean “in the vicinity of which”. Though Erwin Bolwidt is right, _on_ could actually be _too_ specific because it implies life has developed at the surface.

Comment: @Joshua on Earth, we have a thing called _tact_ ... `s/have/had/`

Comment: @abligh my first reaction was "upon which" :)

Comment: As an American English speaker, "where" and "whose" both feel correct, but "whose" sounds much better to me. (Although if I were taking the test, I'd still put B because it's clearly the one they want.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Short answer:**

We can't use the word *that* here.

---

### **Full answer:**

> Hawking believes that the earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ life has developed gradually.

Here we are interested in the last part of the sentence. I'll make it shorter, so it's easy to see what is happening:

- Earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ life has developed gradually.

The second part of this sentence is a relative clause, shown in brackets below:

- Earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ [ life has developed gradually].

**Relative clauses**

Relative clauses are very often used to modify nouns:

1. That's the restaurant **which** [ I like ].
2. That's the restaurant **where** [ I saw Barrack Obama ]

In the examples above, the relative clauses modify the word *restaurant*. Usually there is a relative word at the beginning of the relative clause. The body of the clause comes after this word. In examples (1, 2), the relative words are *which* and *where*. The clauses after the *wh*- words are in brackets, [ ... ]. In restrictive relative clauses like these, we can use the word *that* instead of the word *which*.

If you look at the clauses inside the brackets, you will see that they have gaps in:

- That's the restaurant **which** [ I like __ ].
- That's the restaurant **where** [ I met Barack Obama __ ]

Notice that both the sentences above use the word *restaurant*. It doesn't matter what the noun before the relative clause is. In both the sentences above, we can think of a restaurant as being a place. So how do we decide when to use *which* and when to use *where*?

Well, the word *which* is a pronoun. The word *where* is a locative preposition (some people think of it as a locative adverb). If we need to know whether to use *which* or *where*, we can look at the gap in the relative clause. If we can fill it with a pronoun like *it*, then we need to use the pronoun *which* in the relative clause. If we can fill it with the locative preposition *there*, we need to use the locative *where*. Let's split our examples into two sentences so it is easier to see:

- That's the restaurant. I like __ .
- That's the restaurant. I met Barack Obama __ .

If we fill in those gaps we will see that we need to use *it* in the first sentence and *there* in the second one:

- That's the restaurant. I like **it** .
- That's the restaurant. I met Barack Obama **there** .

We can't do this the other way round!

- That's the restaurant. *I like **there** . (ungrammatical)
- That's the restaurant. *I met Barack Obama **it** . (ungrammatical)

So we understand the sentences like this:

- That's the restaurant **which** [ I like <s>**it**</s>].
- That's the restaurant **where** [ I saw Barrack Obama <s>**there**</s> ]

---

**The Original Poster's example:**

> Earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ [ life has developed gradually __ ].

The gap in the relative clause is at the end here. We can only 'fill it in' with *there*. We couldn't use *it*:

- Earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ [ life has developed gradually <s>there</s> ].
- *Earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ [ life has developed gradually <s>it</s> ]

For this reason we need the relative locative word *where* to go with the locative *there*.

---

<sup>**Grammar Note 1**</sup>

<sup>In actual fact, the Original Poster's sentence could also have a gap before the word *life*:</sup>

<sup>-  Earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ [ __ life has developed gradually].</sup>

<sup>We could fill this gap with a possessive pronoun:</sup>

<sup>-  Earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ [ <s>**its**</s> life has developed gradually].</sup>

<sup>This sentence would give us the impression that maybe there were other planets where life developed fast. If the gap represents a possessive pronoun, we need the possessive relative pronoun *whose*. Remember we use relative *whose* for things as well as people:</sup>

<sup>-  Earth is unlikely to be the only planet whose life has developed gradually.</sup>

<sup>**Grammar Note 2**</sup>

<sup>Notice that the word *place* is unusual. After the word *place* we can use relative clauses with gaps representing locative phrases and we don't need to use the word *where*. Instead we can use no relative word at all, or we can use the relative word *that*:</sup>

<sup>- That's the place we ate last time</sup>

<sup>- Dublin is the place I want to live.</sup>

<sup>- That's the place we saw that incredible film.</sup>

<sup>- This is the place they kept the prisoner.</sup>

<sup>We can't do this with other nouns:</sup>

<sup>- *That's **the restaurant** we ate last time. (ungrammatical)</sup>

<sup>- *Dublin is **the city** I want to live. (ungrammatical)</sup>

<sup>- *That's **the theatre** we saw that incredible film. (ungrammatical)</sup>

<sup>- *This is **the dungeon** they kept the prisoner. (ungrammatical)</sup>

Comment: "that" is preferable to "which" for introducing restrictive clauses.

Comment: @Acccumulation [See this post here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295879/the-film-that-which-i-selected-for-viewing). That is an old wive's tale ;-)

Comment: That question asked whether they are *correct*. I said that "that" is *preferable*.

Comment: @acccumulation Hi, but that's a matter of style, perhaps, no?

Comment: @Araucaria I'm not interested in the "that" vs. "which" debate, but considering the OP specifically asked about "that" and "that" and "which" were both possible answers, the answer could be a little bit confusing.

Comment: Only the word "place" is unusual and has the formula "the place where/that/∅", isn't (or should I say "doesn't"?) it?

Comment: @joiedevivre +1 Good point, I forgot to put that info in. I've had an edit. Is that better?

Comment: @ZhangJian Yes, that's right :)

Comment: @Araucaria But how should I make the question tag? "isn't it" or "doesn't it"?

Comment: @ZhangJian You can't really use a normal question tag felicitously there. But in this fairly informal situation you could say "....., right?" or "...., no?"

Answer (score 24):

It doesn't.

In this circumstance if you said "that life has developed gradually", this would imply life had developed the planet

"that life has developed ON gradually" is correct.

Comment: +1. But we wouldn't say **...where life has developed on**. Not that you're suggesting we do. Just hard to explain.

Comment: Just a warning that some may consider the construction "that <noun> has <verb>-ed on" as being an instance of "ending a sentence with a preposition" (in spite of the adverb at the end in this example), so "that life has developed on [gradually]" could be considered poor style.  Then again, Winston Churchill's rebuke goes a long way to point out the error in this proscription. "This is the type of errant pedantry up with which I will not put."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You could explain it with a thought experiment: whenever you use a relative pronoun other than *that*, try putting **that is the answer to the question** right before it: *earth is unlikely to be the only planet **that is the answer to the question** where life has developed gradually*. The question is, therefore, *Where has life developed gradually?* Fair enough. Does *where has life developed gradually on?* make sense? No. There's nothing *on* could possibly refer to.

Comment: For this construction, I'd say 'upon', not 'on'

Comment: @Magoo: I think 'on' is more natural, but either is technically ok

Comment: But life has developed our planet...

Comment: I hate sentences with two *that*s. Does this even need one? *Stephen Hawking believed the earth is unlikely to be the only planet life has developed on.*

Comment: You are correct that it changes the meaning. I don't know what Hawking believed about it, but many other scientists do believe the development of the planet is due to the gradual effects of life https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/life-and-rocks-may-have-co-evolved-on-earth-180957807/ https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982215010908

Answer (score 8):

**It is the only pub ________ this local beer is served.**

where or that?

It is the only pub where this local beer is served

It is the only pub that serves this local beer.

It is the only pub that this local beer is served at.<sup>some would call this marginal but it's widely used</sup>

**It is the only place __________ the snow never melts.**

It is the only place where the snow never melts.

It is the only place that the snow never melts. <sup>some would call this marginal</sup>

It is the only place the snow never melts.

Comment: One other option: _It is the only pub serving this local beer_. This is harder to do in the negative, though. Perhaps: _This is the only place with never-melting snow_

Comment: "It is the only place that the snow never melts" is not only marginal, but ambiguous. One reading could be rewritten as "the only place never melted by the snow".

Comment: As an aside, "never-melting snow" sounds really poetic - I like it1

Comment: *Where are the never-melting snows of yesteryear?*

Answer (score 4):

There is more than one correct answer (though a bit subjective), but it's not "that".

> Stephen Hawking believes that the earth is unlikely to be the only planet ____ life has developed gradually.
>
> A. that
>   B. where
>   C. which
>   D. whose

In order of brevity:

**Where**

Is correct. "the planet" can be considered a location, so you can say "the planet where life has developed".

**Whose**

Is also correct, *if* you consider "Earth's life" to be a valid interpretation. Though it relies on a personification of Earth, that isn't too far-fetched. We can reference *mother* nature, which is the same (albeit more overt) type of personification.

We say things like "the Earth's crust", "the Earth's atmosphere", ... I consider "the Earth's life" to be equally correct from a *grammatical* perspective, regardless of it being more poetic than the other examples.

I consider this correct; and I'm interested in anyone who has a *specific* counterclaim that it is incorrect.

**That**

Is not correct. However, I do think I see why you think it is. There is a very similar sentence in which "that" would be correct.

This is not correct:

> Stephen Hawking believes that the earth is unlikely to be the only planet that life has developed gradually.

This is correct:

> Stephen Hawking believes that the earth is unlikely to be the only planet that **has developed life**  gradually.

In this second example, **the planet** (subject) **developed life** (object), rather than saying "life developed [itself]" (which is what the original sentence is conveying).

If that is what you want to say, then you can also say "the planet that developed life" or "the planet that has developed life".

This again rests on the implicit personification of the planet, similar to my explanation in "whose", which I still think is a correct interpretation.

However, given the question's specific phrasing, "that" is not a correct answer to this question.

**Which**

Is not correct. However, there are nearby versions that are correct:

> 1. Stephen Hawking believes that the earth is unlikely to be the only planet which **has developed life** gradually.

Similar to my explanation in "that", this relies on the notion that **the planet** (subject) **developed life** (object).

> 2. Stephen Hawking believes that the earth is unlikely to be the only planet **on which** has developed life gradually.

"On which" is the first thing I though of when I saw your question title (before I read the question body). It is more idiomatic than the given options.

"On which" is correct for the same reason that "where" is correct; because "the planet" can be considered a location. And in English, we say "**on** the planet", not "**in** the planet", which is why "on which" is correct and "in which" is not.

Comment: "on which" or "in which"  is more formal, and perhaps more akin to ancient Latin but I wouldn't say it is more idiomatic. Can you provide supporting evidence? For example, "*This is the hotel in which I stayed*" vs. "*This is the hotel where I stayed*" My bet is that the latter is far more common.